# WebLogic Admin server changes not persisting across restarts

Tags: weblogic11g

A startAdmin.sh server script which is used to start the administration server was written with the following lines at the end:

```
DATE=/usr/bin/date +%d
/usr/bin/cp -pr /opt/bea/user_projects/domains/Domain/servers/Admin /opt/bea/user_projects/domains/Domain/servers/Admin.BCk.${DATE}
/usr/bin/rm -rf /opt/bea/user_projects/domains/Domain/servers/Admin/*

${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/startWebLogic.sh >>  ${INSTANCE_LOGS} 2>&1 &
```

It creates a backup of the current Admin server then removes contents of the current instance. My problem is that when I create users and groups it gets overwritten with the default settings on each restart, as with everything else.
Can you all advise me on where the contents of the Admin server is being copied back? Is it in the startWebLogic.sh? If so, what commands or configuration tags do I look for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not remove everything under the `domain\servers\Admin` folder. You can probably remove the tmp/stage/cache folder under the Admin folder, but you should not delete others such as **data** folder. For example, the embedded ldap data are stored under data\ldap\ldapfiles. That stores the data for all the internal users/groups. If they are not their, weblogic tries to load the default settings. Taht's why your users/groups get lost after every restart.

Lan

Comment: I am aware of this, but I am told to find exactly where the files are being copied back. I've looked through the setDomainEnv.sh and startWebLogic.sh but the problem is I'm not familiar with scripting and not sure what exactly to look for.